# Postgresql drivers not found when dockerizing TeamCity

Tags: postgresql, docker, teamcity

I want to use a [Docker image to run TeamCity](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2014/07/easy-teamcity-installation-with-docker.html). But I can't get further than to the database collection when choosing Postgresql. (The built in memory database works fine though.) Apparently, even if I place the jar file containing the driver into the request directory, it is not recognized.

This is how I start the containers:

```
$ sudo docker run --restart=always -d --name tc-postgres omq_/teamcity-postgres:9.4
$ sudo docker run -d --name tc-server -p 8111:8111 --link tc-postgres:tc-postgreslink ariya/centos6-teamcity-server
```

This is the error message:

```
The PostgreSQL JDBC driver is not found in the /data/teamcity/lib/jdbc directory. Download the JDBC41 driver from jdbc.postgresql.org and place it to this directory.
```

And it remains even after creating `lib/jdbc` and copying the jar file over like

```
$ cp postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/569bab307f99d53e21b584026a15251ab7d5382d2982431558a1a5dac056dfaa/data/teamcity/lib/jdbc
```

and pushing the Refresh JDBC drivers button Restarting the container makes no difference.

[image: Database connection setup]

Ignoring the requirement and entering credentials to proceed results in the error `No suitable JDBC driver found for database type: PostgreSQL` showing up.

Comment: Can you try this, if it works I can probably provide a Dockerfile file that you can use to build the postgres driver into your image: ```docker run -dt -name teamcity_server -p 8111:8111 -v /you/hosts/path/to/the/jdbc/drivers:/data/teamcity/lib/jdbc ariya/centos6-teamcity-server``` . If your docker run command differs greatly, please update your post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks! When I try this, I get to a page telling me `TeamCity has failed to start` and `Error: the JDBC drivers subdirectory "/data/teamcity/lib/jdbc" is not a directory.`

Comment: Finally worked. My error placing the filepath not the directory in the volume option.

Comment: you should post your answer and accept it. it will help search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mounting the directory (not the file) solved the issue.

```
docker run -dt -name teamcity_server -p 8111:8111 -v /you/hosts/path/to/the/jdbc:/data/teamcity/lib/jdbc ariya/centos6-teamcity-server
```